# How to dynamically get a property?

Tags: python

I have this python code:

```
class MyObject:
    def __init__(self):
        self._obj1 = "obj1"
        self._obj2 = "obj2"

    @property
    def obj1(self):
        return self._obj1
    @property
    def obj2(self):
        return self._obj2

def get_property(obj, chose):
    if chose == "obj1":
        return obj.obj1
    elif chose == "obj2":
        return obj.obj2

test1 = MyObject()
test2 = MyObject()
config = {"obj1": test1, "obj2":test2}

for key, value in config.items():
    #my_value = value.key  <<- how make it works?
    my_value = get_property(value, key)
    print(my_value)
```

As you can see, I will have to manually create a big list of `get_property` to translate the value. How can I make it more dynamically and this code just works:

```
for key, value in config.items():
    my_value = value.key
```

Comment: Why not just use `getattr(obj, 'attrname')` instead of your custom `get_property` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getattr(obj, 'attrname')`. In your code:

```
for key, value in config.items():
    my_value = getattr(value, key)
```

Comment: Argh... This exist.. I didn't find it.. Thanks.